# how to format time from HH:MM:SS to HHMM in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet in which one of the column is transaction time and its format is HH:MM:SS. But I need transaction time in HHMM format so that i can upload that excel sheet into my application. As of now i am manually formatting each row, is there any way i can apply required format to whole column at once?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**If for your eyes only:**

select whole column, right click somewhere in your selection, go to Format Cells, tab Number, Catergory Custom.

Type HHmm

Press OK

done.

**If you need this as the actual value:**

make a column containing the following formula `=TEXT(<targetcell>;"HHmm")`

Note that it is language-dependant whether you need a , or ; in that formula.

Comment: please markt he answer as such, so other will know. Glad to have been of help to you

Comment: Note that it is language-dependant whether you need a `,` or `;` in that formula

Comment: @Meysam dont fix what aint broken. , and ; fulfill the same role, depending on your language settings. See Hans Kesting's comment...

Comment: @K_B I'm sorry dude, I didn't know that. I thought only VBA could be used in Excel formulas. What other languages can be used?

Comment: @Maysam I was referring to human languages like English, German, Spanish. Continental Western Europe uses the comma as decimal separator,  Imperial countries use the period. As Western Europe uses the comma for decimal we cannot use it also for separating arguments or parameters. Therefore we use the semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

- Custom format the field.
- Use a function in another cell. Suppose, cell `A1` contains the text `15:48:58`. You use the formula in another cell (say B1) as `=TEXT(HOUR(A1),"00")&TEXT(MINUTE(A1),"00")`. This gives the output as `1548`.

Comment: The second option gives 05:09 as 59, which is not what you would wwant. Expand this to: `=TEXT(HOUR(A1),"00")&TEXT(MINUTE(A1),"00")`

Comment: @K_B Thanks... I have edited the post accordingly :)

Answer (score -1):

For example, type `.633` in `B2` cell. When we convert `0.633` to time means we convert `0.633`day. We consider 24 hours as 1 day.

Follow the steps:

1. Select B2 cell and right click.
2. From shortcut menu, go to Format cells. Format cells dialog box appears.
3. In the dialog box. click custom under Category list. Find `hh:mm:ss` from right list.
4. Now edit it as `hhmmss` in the right side just under 'Type:'.

You may read this tutorial from msofficeworld: [Format Time in Excel](http://msofficeworld.com/format-time-in-excel/)